# Socket.io - SSL through Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl, cloudflare

I've read through nearly every possible tutorial about how to receive SSL through socket.io and I just can't seem to get it to work.

My backend JS is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/crt.crt'),
    requestCert: true
};
var app = express();
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(2096, "IP Address");
```

The frontend JS:

```
SOCKET = io('https://name.com:443', {secure: true});
```

I'm using full SSL, with cloudflare signed certificates install on my server.

I also receive the following error when connecting:

```
POST https://name.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LcBk2Vk 404()
```

I'm not sure if my ports are incorrect or I'm missing something entirely.

I'm happy to provide more code snippets.

Thanks in advance

Comment: don't you need a wss:// url? does that wss connect to a plain WebSocket()? (just temporarily)

Comment: You are trying to connect to port `443` while your server is listening on port `2096`. Try https://name.com:2096

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply listening on the wrong port. SSL traffic is served over 443 usually, in order to fix this you should substitute:

`server.listen(2096, "IP Address");`

With something like this:

`server.listen(443);`